# How to upload image in reactive form in Angular?

Tags: angular, file-upload

I'm using reactive form for update my user data.
First I get user data from API response & display to the user after which I want to upload my image & other data but somehow I can't.

Problem is everytime I submit form it return flows after if condition which I applied for checking my form is valid or not, but I don't get it my form is invalid.

Here is my component.ts file code:

```
constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private amen: AmenService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUserDetails();

        this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            mobile: ['', Validators.required],
            user_img: ['']
        });
   }


    getUserDetails() {
        this.amen.getUserDetails(this.params).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.updateForm.patchValue(this.handleResponse(response));
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
            }
        );
    }

    handleResponse(response) {
        if (response.status === 1) {
            return response.responseData.UserData;
        }
        if (response.status === 0) {
            this.forAlertBox = true;
            this.msg = response.msg;
        }
    }

    preview(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0].name;
            this.updateForm.get('file').valueChanges.subscribe(
                 value=> {  
                      this.selectedImage = value;  
                 } 
            );
        }
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.spinner.show();
        this.submitted = true;

        // return flow if form is invalid
        if (this.updateForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('user_img', this.selectedImage);
        formData.append('name', this.updateForm.get('name').value);
        formData.append('email', this.updateForm.get('email').value);
        formData.append('mobile', this.updateForm.get('mobile').value);

        this.amen.updateUserProfile(formData).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleUpdateResponse(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('after update error', error);
            }
        );
    }

    handleUpdateResponse(response) {
        if (response.status === 1) {
            this.router.navigate(['edit-my-profile']);
        }

        if (response.status === 0) {
            this.forAlertBox = true;
            this.msg = response.msg;
        }
    }
```

Here is the link of stackblitz editor. It get me errors but you will come to know what I'm doing.
https://angular-ak6grp.stackblitz.io

Comment: Please post a html code, And which field you are getting invalid in If block?

Comment: @hrdkisback Please check the bottom of the post I tried to create a stackblitz link which will get you idea of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I think the above link is not accessible. It's showing loading.

Comment: @hrdkisback Please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ak6grp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html